# Putting new HDD on old PC, then putting back old HDD

Tags: hard-drive

I have a desktop computer now (Dec. 2022) and I am planning to buy a laptop next year. So I will also sell this computer next year. But I have the **old HDD** I am using right now and want to keep it. I am planning to put a **new HDD** which I will include with the computer when I sell it.

My question is:
If I remove my **old HDD** now (with my important personal files), and put a **new HDD** and install all the windows update and drivers to it, then I put back my **old HDD**, will it still work? Will my files be safe on the old HDD and my computer will normally run for this year (before I sell my computer)?

Comment: What OS are we talking about

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: If you are dependent on that one disk for all of your personal data, life is going to suck if you ever need a backup of it.

Comment: @RohitGupta Windows 10

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - I have many HDDs, it is just my main HDD for this computer that is why I want to use it before I sell this computer.

Comment: You should have backups anyway if your personal files are important. Little makes sense in your question to be honest.

Comment: This question makes no sense to me. If you buy a new laptop it will have an SSD. It sounds as if the only thing you need is transferring relevant data from the desktop HDD to the laptop SSD, then wiping the HDD. The HDD will not even fit in the laptop. No need to buy a new HDD.